# Can somebody log in to my system as www-data?

Tags: security, apache-httpd

The Apache2 install creates a user and group named "www-data" apparently with no password, blank. It uses this user account to run under.

Doesn't this create a security problem because if the account has no password, then somebody could just log in to my system as www-data?

Answer (score 3):

No. Because the default shell for `www-data` is `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Here's how it looks on one of the (Debian) servers I operate:

```
getent passwd | grep www
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

And here is what happens when you try to change into that user:

```
sudo su www-data
This account is currently not available.
```

Comment: Not `www-data:*`? That’s odd... What does `/etc/shadow` contain for `www-data`?

Comment: @StephenKitt This: `www-data:*:17340:0:99999:7:::`

Comment: OK, that’s better.